# jquery only working once

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists, toggle

I've got a ul with hidden list elements in default state:

```
$(function () {
    $("li.closed > ul").hide();
});
```

On Click I show the hidden list elements with toggling.

```
$("ul > li.closed").click(function () {
    var li = $(this).closest('li');
    li.find(' > ul').slideToggle('fast');
    $(this).toggleClass("closed open");
});
```

Everything is just working fine. But when I visit another page and return to my previous, the toggle is not working anymore - when I click they toggle out and instantly toggle back in.

I'm loading my links in a div with this:

```
$(".link").click(function (e) {
    // Prevent the default action of the event
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkHref = this.id + '.html';
    $("#content").load(linkHref);
    $("#nav a.active").toggleClass('inactive active');
    $(this).addClass("active").removeClass('inactive');
});
```

and therefore my html pages only exists of the body part and I'm loading the global.js everytime again, could this be a problem (with like caching or something)? Like this:

```
<script src="js/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<article>    
    <ul>
        <li class="closed">Headline
            <ul>
                <li class="fl"><a href="#"><img src="x.png"></a></li>
                <li class="fl"><a href="#"><img src="x.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of having this -

```
$(function () {
    $("li.closed > ul").hide();
});
```

Remove the above jQuery code and insert this into your CSS

```
li.closed > ul {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Ok it is working now, thank you. But now it keeps hiding the list elements again when I click on one of them while they are open. Any ideas?

Comment: Try removing this line.    $(this).toggleClass("closed open");

Comment: Unfortunately no difference. And I need this line to toggle my classes - I got different open:before and closed:before styles that I need.